# I got this error when I run my react project

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

```
Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {pathname, search, hash, state}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
```

Bakery.js

```
import React from "react";

import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

import "../Styles/Filter.css";

function Bakery(props){

return(

\<div\>

\<Link to='/details' className="btn"\>

\<div className="row result-section ms-md-3 mb-3 p-4"\>

\<div className="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3"\>

\<img

className="thumb"

src={require("../Assets/breakfast.jpg").default}

alt="Restaurant Thumb"

/\>

\</div\>

\<div className="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-9"\>

<h3>

{props.name}</h3>


<h5>

{props.place}</h5>


<h6>

{props.location}</h6>


\</div\>

<hr className="line-break mt-3" />


\<div className="row"\>

\<div className="col-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-4"\>

\<table className="table-transparent"\>

\<thead\>

\<tr\>

\<th scope="row"\>CUISINES:\</th\>

\<td\>{props.cuisine}\</td\>

\</tr\>

\</thead\>

\<tbody\>

\<tr\>

\<th scope="row"\>COST FOR TWO:\</th\>

\<td\>{props.cost}\</td\>

\</tr\>

\</tbody\>

\</table\>

\</div\>

\</div\>

\</div\>

\</Link\>

\</div\>);

}

export default Bakery;
```

Filter.js

```
          <Bakery name="The Big Chill Cakery"  place="FORT" location="Shop 1, Plot D, Samruddhi Complex, Chincholi …" cuisine="Bakery" cost={700}/>
```

Comment: Please correct the code formatting. Also edit the question to include desired behaviour, and a description of the error. Basically add some description to help us understand

Comment: That's really hard to read; I might recommend putting the code in again, properly formatted. The error generally indicates you're trying to display "an object" instead of a simple value like a string or a number, or have missed a component.

Comment: I echo the above comments about readability. But I think your proplem is `props.location` - it looks (from the keys on the object it's complaining about) like you've accidentally passed in a `location` object from React Router (which I see you are definitely using) where I guess it was supposed to be a simple string. The faulty code is likely to  be in the parent component of this one.

Comment: (Also, as an accessibility-related aside, you shouldn't be using heading elements like your h3, h5 and h6 here without actual content afterwards - because they're not actually being used as headings. Also if they were headings, they need to go down sequentially, so there would be an h4 between the h3 and h5. It seems like you're using those just for styling/formatting, in which case don't, use <p> tags or similar and use CSS for styling.)